# Using Concatenation in Import file using vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to have a dynamic name for my json file when importing.
I am using Vue JS and i have this code

```
Import MY_JSON from './2018-05-at-2018-05-18.json'
export default {
     data() {
         return {

         }
}
```

i want to make it like this

```
Import MY_JSON from './2018-05-at-' + date + '.json'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            date: '2018-05-18'
        }
    }
```

i tried it but it doesn't work, i tried to search to google but it doesn't give me a result that i want. Hope someone could help me. THANKS!

Comment: why not to use ajax to request these json files?

Comment: i have over 500mb of files.. my website slows down because of the huge amount of data being requested.. i tried to use json file and it makes it fast..

Comment: @jacky can you show me how to do it? i misunderstood your comment.. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is for static files but `require` could work for you

```
const MY_JSON = require('./2018-05-at-' + date + '.json')
```

Comment: i just tried it now and the error says date is not defined. I added 'date" into data(). Still error occured.

Comment: It's a wrong way to do that,If you do so, the 500M files will be packaged into vendor.js, your site will only be slower.Also, both import and require are executed at compile time, not run time.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how javascript works. date has to be defined before the import statement. And even if this works.. @jacky is right, what you want is probably doing an ajax request.

Comment: @jacky yes i agree. I am just answering the exact question. Pls provide an answer about ajax? since it's ur idea first

Comment: I just means to send ajax request to get json file's content

Comment: @jacky yup i know. I just don't wanna make you feel like i steal your answer, that's all

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to require json file after `this.date` was defined.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>loading..</h1>
    <span>{{ json }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      date: '2018-05-18',
      json: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.json = require('../test-' + this.date + '.json')
  },
}
</script>
```